# How do you perform a git command on the root commit in git using system calls in code?

Tags: python, git

I would like to be able to the the SHA of the root commit in a git repository

The catch is that I am using a script to automate a certain git task that I need to be performed many times on various repositories.

I am using the function `system()`, C's standard library function for making system calls, and most languages have an equivalent.

The following process does not work with `system()`:

1. **get** SHAs of all commits with `system("<git command for listing SHAs here>")` <– this outputs text to the command line rather than returning a list of values to the code
2. **find** SHA of root commit <– this cannot happen if the code cannot get a list of all commits
3. **run** `system("<git command here> <SHA of root commit>")`

It is possible the command I am looking for looks like this:

```
system("git checkout root");
```

If this is the case, what is the command? If this is not the case, what is the appropriate solution? Is there a better alternative to this that doesn't use `system()` (the function for executing commands in C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there is not necessarily a single root commit: given N ≥ 1 commits there is at *at least* one root, but there could be more than one.

That said, each commit has a backwards link to its parent(s), unless it is a root commit, which by definition has no parent.  So given any commit hash, you can find its root(s) by walking the graph backwards.  If you start at all reachable commits and walk all paths, you will find *all* root commits.

There is a Git command that does precisely that: `git rev-list`.  You give it some set of starting point commit specifiers, and it walks the graph.  By default, it emits every commit hash ID as it comes across it, but it takes many options, including those that limit its output.  For instance, it has the `--min-parents` and `--max-parents` options that tell it to emit only commits that have at least min, and at most max, parents.  Hence:

```
git rev-list --all --max-parents=0
```

emits all root commits, as found from all references (`--all`).

> [`git rev-list`] outputs text to the command line rather than returning a list data structure to code

It outputs text to *standard output*.  Any sensible programming language and operating system offers a way to capture that output:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-list', '--all', '--max-parents=0'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()
result = proc.wait()
```

for instance.  (If using Python 3, note that `output` is made up of `bytes` rather than `str`.)  You can then parse the output into a series of lines, to find the root commits.  If there is more than one root, it's up to you to decide what to do about this.

Since `git rev-list` is a plumbing command, its output is generally designed to be machine readable.

> `system("git rebase <SHA of root commit>")`

It's rarely sensible to rebase a complex history, but if you have a simple history, this could be fine.  Having a simple history may also guarantee you a single root commit: it could be wise to *verify* (using the output of `git rev-list --parents`, for instance) that you do in fact have a simple history.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful and thorough answer. I am a complete beginner to both system calls and git, and your answer was very easy to follow.